# How To Allow CRM Plugin To Handle Multiple Event Messages

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I need to create a single plugin to fire on create, update, and delete events of opportunity entities.

Can I do these in a single plugin?  If so then how can I do them?

Comment: Does your question refer to using a single plugin to run on create/update/delete plugin messages on the opportunity entity? 
Your question is tagged for crm 2011 but crm 2013 sdk, which one is it? Please be specific and make it clear in your problem description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can use same plugin to execute it on create,update and delete

write your plugin as follows..

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
          IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
           IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
           IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

           if (context.MessageName == "Create") 
           {
             //write the logic what you want this plugin to do on Create
           }
           if (context.MessageName == "Update") 
           {
            //write the logic what you want this plugin to do on Update
           }
           if (context.MessageName == "Delete") 
           {
            //write the logic what you want this plugin to do on Delete
           }  
}
```

> Register your plugin on Create,Update,Delete for Oppertunity Entity using Plugin registration
>   tool

it should work

Answer (score 3):

Your plugin has to implement the `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPlugin` interface which just has a single method to implement, `Execute`.  Within your `Execute` method, you'll need to inspect the IPluginExecutionContext's `MessageName` property and check to see what type of event triggered the plugin.  You'll also need to register the plugin for each message type (Create/Update/Delete) via the plugin registration tool.

Here is my personal list of OOB message types to compare to the `MessageName`:

```
AddItem,
AddListMembers,
AddMember,
AddMembers,
AddPrincipalToQueue,
AddPrivileges,
AddProductToKit,
AddRecurrence,
AddToQueue,
AddUserToRecordTeam,
Assign,
AssignUserRoles,
Associate,
BackgroundSend,
Book,
Cancel,
CheckIncoming,
CheckPromote,
Clone,
Close,
CopyDynamicListToStatic,
CopySystemForm,
Create,
CreateException,
CreateInstance,
Delete,
DeleteOpenInstances,
DeliverIncoming,
DeliverPromote,
DetachFromQueue,
Disassociate,
Execute,
ExecuteById,
Export,
ExportAll,
ExportCompressed,
ExportCompressedAll,
GenerateSocialProfile,
GrantAccess,
Handle,
Import,
ImportAll,
ImportCompressedAll,
ImportCompressedWithProgress,
ImportWithProgress,
LockInvoicePricing,
LockSalesOrderPricing,
Lose,
Merge,
ModifyAccess,
PickFromQueue,
Publish,
PublishAll,
QualifyLead,
Recalculate,
ReleaseToQueue,
RemoveFromQueue,
RemoveItem,
RemoveMember,
RemoveMembers,
RemovePrivilege,
RemoveProductFromKit,
RemoveRelated,
RemoveUserFromRecordTeam,
RemoveUserRoles,
ReplacePrivileges,
Reschedule,
Retrieve,
RetrieveExchangeRate,
RetrieveFilteredForms,
RetrieveMultiple,
RetrievePersonalWall,
RetrievePrincipalAccess,
RetrieveRecordWall,
RetrieveSharedPrincipalsAndAccess,
RetrieveUnpublished,
RetrieveUnpublishedMultiple,
RetrieveUserQueues,
RevokeAccess,
Route,
RouteTo,
Send,
SendFromTemplate,
SetRelated,
SetState,
SetStateDynamicEntity,
TriggerServiceEndpointCheck,
UnlockInvoicePricing,
UnlockSalesOrderPricing,
Update,
ValidateRecurrenceRule,
Win
```